# Using nanoframework with esp32, how do I permanently flassingmy program?

Tags: c#, esp32, nanoframework

I already have my program and it works in visual studio, now: how do I make this program stay permanently in esp32?

I understand that you have to save the .bin image generated by visual studio using the nanoff command (`nanoff --target ESP32_WROOM_32 --serialport COM12 --deploy --image "E: \ GitHub \ nf-Samples \ samples \ Blinky \ Blinky \ bin \ Debug \ Blinky.bin "--address 0x190000`).

However after saving the image and feeding the circuit by USB it seems not to start ...

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is not because the program doesn't remain in memory, it's because the build you're using has a setting that forces the CLR to wait for a debugger to connect when it exits the application execution.

To start over you have to reset the MCU and it will start over again.

FYI: the stable firmware versions provided don't have this setting enabled. Or you can build your own and change the setting.